# Spring batch- creating a file and then reading from the same file

Tags: spring-batch

I am supposed to read from multiple files and then write into a single file after applying some processing and transforming logic.
In order to do so, I have created a single batch job with 3 steps, where the 1st and 2nd steps are responsible for reading the data and writing in an intermediary temporary file, and finally in the 3rd or the last step I am trying to read that temporary file and apply the final logic to create the end file.

The error I am getting is:

- Always the intermediate temporary file is getting created successfully as an end result of step 1 and step 2, but step 3 fails to create the final file.
- Step 3 is able to find and read from that file and also was successful in preparing the data, but the file is never getting created.
- Spring Batch is throwing a MojoException, and it is hard to find the actual cause.
- For testing, if I keep the temporary file pre-created and directly run the last step, then the final file gets created successfully. But when all the steps are running and this temporary file is created on the fly, only then this error occurs.
- I have tried with `start-next` steps and also with `flow`, i.e., `start`-`on(COMPLTED)`-`to`-`end` approach, but every time, the same results.
- Finally, I have made `transactional` as `false` and `forceSync` as `true` in the writer but with no luck.

Below is a snippet from the writer and the job:

```
new FlatFileOutputWriter(
    new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyPOJO>()
        .name("lastFileWriter")
        .resource(new FileSystemResource("<THE PATH TO THE TEMPORARY FILE, THAT WAS CRATD IN THE PREVIOUS STEP>"))
        .shouldDeleteIfEmpty(true)
        .lineAggregator(
                (item) -> item.id() + fieldDelimeter + item.value())
        .append(false)
        .transactional(false)
        .forceSync(true)
        .build()
)
```

Below is the snippet of the job:

```
return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
    .listener(jobCompletionListener)
    .start(step1)
    .on("COMPLETD").to(step2)
    .on("COMPLETD").to(step3)
    .end()
    .build();
```

Can anyone please provide some insights or suggestion on this?

Comment: Is the job flow you shared correct? As I understand the description, it should it be something like `.start(step1).on("COMPLETD").to(step2).from(step2).on("COMPLETD").to(step3)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are correct. I am still learning Spring Batch, was not very clear on this conditional flow.
I shall try your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to accomplish the requirement. Here is the logic I used-

1. Step 1 will be reading the file and save the processed data in `H2 DB`
2. Step 2 will do the same as step 1 using a different processor
3. In the final step, data will be read from that `H2 DB`'s table and written in the final file
4. With the above approach, simply use `next()` to apply sequential flow, instead of conditional flow of `from()`, `to()` and `on()`

So, the snippet should look something like this-

```
.start(step1, that will read the file and store in DB)
.next(step2, that will read another file and store in DB)
.next(step3, that will fetch the data from the DB and write in the file)
```

*Note:*
If the data are directly being written in the file after being fetched from the `DB`, without any processing, then DON'T use any processor, i.e., the `step` (final one) will be only having a `reader` (to fetch from the `DB`) and a `writer` (to write in the file).

Comment: Sounds ok so long as you use file storage for h2 database, otherwise memory consumption could be excessive.  I have batch jobs that use ehcache configured to use disk storage for jobs with multiple steps that enrich objects stored in the cache, then iterate through the cache at the end and write to file.